# Получить все варианты перевода слова с Google Translate API

Tags: java, google-translate

Я пишу процессинг для пословного перевода текста с использованием Google translate API. Но в ответе API возвращает только один из возможных вариантов первода. Пример кода:

```
TranslationServiceClient client =
                TranslationServiceClient.create();
        LocationName parent = LocationName.of(projectId, "global");

        TranslateTextRequest request =
                TranslateTextRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setParent(parent.toString())
                        .setMimeType("text/plain")
                        .setTargetLanguageCode("en")
                        .addContents("замок")
                        .build();
        TranslateTextResponse response = client.translateText(request);
```

Получаю только один вариант:

```
translated_text: "lock"
detected_language_code: "ru"
```

Есть ли возможность получить все возможные варианты? Для конкретного примера:

```
translated_text: "lock", "castle"
detected_language_code: "ru"
```

В доке про multiply translation ничего не нашел.

P.S. Для тех, кто тоже столкнулся с этой проблеммой и не привязан имено к Google, я нашел нужные возможности у Microsoft Azure translator

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [здесь](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-translate/latest/com/google/cloud/translate/v3beta1/TranslationServiceClient.html), возможно вам подойдет ListGlossariesPagedResponse